# Unable to create index while sharding

Tags: mongodb

When i am trying to enable the shard... I am getting following errors........

```
use admin
switched to db admin
> db.runCommand( { enablesharding : "sgserver" } )
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "sgserver.block_seek_pos", key : {fileGUID : 1} } )

"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "please create an index over the sharding key before sharding."

> db.sgserver.ensureIndex({"fileGUID": 1})
> db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "sgserver.block_seek_pos", key : {fileGUID : 1} } )

"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "please create an index over the sharding key before sharding."
```

Its insisting that I create an index, but if I try to create an index I am getting the above mentioned error.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the `sgserver` collection inside of the `admin` database?

I don't see the command where you switch to the correct database before you do `ensureIndex()`. The code should probably look like this:

```
db.runCommand( { enablesharding : "sgserver" } );
use sgserver;
db.sgserver.ensureIndex({"fileGUID": 1});
db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "sgserver.block_seek_pos", key : {fileGUID : 1} } )
```